# mysql copy some rows and update one column

Tags: mysql, insert-update

i read the question with a similar title but it doesn't match my problem.

I have this table

```
Robot_Minions
id | type   | id_robot_master
1  | catbot | 15
2  | dogbot | 15
3  | batbot | 15
```

What I want to do is copy all the Robot_Minons of Robot_Master 15 and assign them to Robot_Master 16.

So the end result should look like

```
Robot_Minions
id | type   | id_robot_master
1  | catbot | 15
2  | dogbot | 15
3  | batbot | 15
4  | catbot | 16
5  | dogbot | 16
6  | batbot | 16
```

One way I can think of to do it is to first select the rows to be copied, then loop through them and run an INSERT blah then UPDATE blah WHERE id=last insert id.  But this is 1+2x queries.  Is there a better way, ideally as one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you already know the id of the robot_master you wish to assign the minions to you can use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Robot_minions (type,id_robot_master)
SELECT type, '<new robot_master_id>' 
FROM Robot_minions
WHERE id_robot_master = '<old robot_master>'
```

this will select the minions that belong to the `<old robot_master>` and then insert the end resultset into `Robot_minions` with the `<new robot_master_id>`